# Webclient download file with size zero when downloading more than once

Tags: c#, webclient

I have a weird problem and I can't find why it happen, I wrote a function to download a file from a given link, when I invoke the function once it works fine. but if I invoke it twice or more (on the same link), it downloads a file with size 0.

Here my code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf");
string outPath = @"D:\tttt\pdf-test.pdf";
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
     using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
     {
         WebProxy wp = new WebProxy($"http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8002/", true);
         webClient.Proxy = wp;
         webClient.OpenRead(uri);
         webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, outPath);
     }
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

This works only for one iteration
but if I'm changing to for loop with two or more iteration the downloaded file will be with size zero

Comment: Lot of code there, what is wrong with simply calling                 webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, outPath);

Comment: @MattEvans Was going to say the same thing

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: You're not waiting for the download to finish before you dispose of the `WebClient`. I would strongly suggest using `HttpClient` instead, and a proper async method - it makes it easier to avoid this sort of thing.

Comment: Maybe the size is 0 because it's still downloading the file.
Do you have some method which catches the [DownloadFileCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted?view=netframework-4.8) event?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you, with `HttpClient` it works